# Show hidden table, onclick

Tags: jquery, css, ruby

I have a hidden table that I'd like to show after the user clicks the search button.  I followed a few examples on here, but can't seem to get this to work.  I can hide the results, but can't get them to appear after the search button is hit.  What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<h1>SEARCH</h1>

<%=search_form_for @search, url: user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Plan_Name_cont, "Name Contains" %>
    <%= f.text_field :Plan_Name_cont %>
</div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Participants_gteq, "Participants Between" %>
    <%= f.text_field :Participants_gteq %>
    <%= f.label :Participants_lteq, "and" %>
    <%= f.text_field :Participants_lteq %>
</div>
 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>


<div class="hidden">
<table>
  <tr>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Plan_Name, "Plan Name" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Method, "Filing Method" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Participants, "Participants" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Type, "Filing Type" %></th>
</tr>

  <body>
    <% @fives.each do |five| %>
    <tr>
         <td><%= five.Plan_Name %> </td>
         <td><%= five.Filing_Method %> </td>
         <td><%= five.Participants %> </td>
         <td><%= five.Filing_Type %> </td>
    <tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
<%= will_paginate @fives %>
</div>
</div>
```

**User CSS**

```
div.hidden { display: none; }
```

**Application.js**

```
$("table").on("click", function(){
    $("div:hidden").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer would work fine but I think I tend to use this approach:

1. make a css class:

   ```
   .hidden { display: none }
   ```
2. use this JS:

   ```
   $("table").off("click").on("click", function(e){
     var $table = $(e.currentTarget)
     $table.toggleClass("hidden")
   });
   ```

By using `$(e.currentTarget)` you're selecting only the table that was clicked, whereas using `$("div:hidden")` you'd be selecting all the hidden tables. Note that `$("div:hidden")` and `$("div.hidden")` are not the same.

If the table should be hidden when the page loads, add the `hidden` class in the HTML.

The `off("click")` part is optional and may make no difference. But it can help if for some reason you're getting duplicate events.

Comment: thanks for your help @max pleaner, but I can't get this to work.  I checked to make sure my javascript was working and it works for other functions.  Like I said, I have no problems hiding the table, but can't seem to get them to show after hitting my search button.  Note, the search results are coming from a large database that is being queried.  As you can see up top, I have a form_for and f.submit that is being clicked in order to generate the results.  That's the only thing I can think of at this point.

Comment: put a debugger statement in your onclick event and figure out the correct code in the dev console.

Comment: okay let me see what I can find.  I tested other jquery and javascript functions and everything else works perfectly.  I just can't get this table to appear.

Comment: Really try debugger. It will help immensly

Comment: thanks, Max.  I was able to find a solution, thanks to your help.

Comment: Cool. I realize my answer wasn't totally correct because you'd be hiding the table after clicked so you wouldn't be able to click it again to open it. But glad you grokked the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method call in jquery css and assign the display: block the div and when you focus on the search txt hide the div , for example

[code to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/duah80Lh/1/)

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.hidden { display: none; }
</style>

</head>
```

```
<h1>SEARCH</h1>

<input type="text" id="textSearch" name="" value="" placeholder="Input Search Value">
<input type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="Search">


<div class="hidden">
    <table>
        <caption>table title and/or explanatory text</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#search").on("click", function(){
    $("div.hidden").css('display', 'block');
})
$("#textSearch").on("focus", function(){
     $("div.hidden").css('display', 'none');
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dev Joel.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work.  Your demo works perfectly, but I can't seem to make the connection with this code to mine.  More specifically, I'm looking to have the hidden table appear, after a user enters hits f.submit in my form_for.  So I'm unclear what your input type="text" etc.. code is referring to.  In my view code above, you can see my form_for builder.  Once the user adds search fields and hits f.submit, I'd like the results in the hidden table to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here man edit yor js and change

```
$("table").on("click", function(){
   $("div.hidden").removeClass("hidden").addClass( "yourClass" );
});
```

good luck man